# Trouble connecting to temperature controller using MODBUS,RS485 and MATLAB

Tags: serial, digital-communications, matlab, rs485, modbus

I am trying to communicate with a temperaturature controller [ATR-401](https://www.ucontrol.com.au/manuals/atr401_it_eng.pdf) using MATLAB but i am having trouble just connecting to it and reading temperature data.I have set baud rate, data bits, parity and stop bits based on the user manual but it still does not recognize the device. The image below shows my code:

[image]

The image below shows my device manager : 
[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your "device manager" window with the "COM & Ports" section expanded.

Comment: i have added an image of my device manager

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Do you have any other programs open? If not, can you use a program like realterm or teraterm to connect to your controller?

Comment: i have used TeraTerm and set the settings but all i see is a black screen and cursor

Comment: Also, I have a strong feeling you may need to convert your single quote (') to double quote (") on lines 7 and 13.

Comment: You can check Modbus with different free software.

Comment: I guess it is solved maybe?

Comment: No , it did not, i am using MODBUS poll software and it keeps showing as Timeout error, but based on datasheet, the timeout is set to 20ms based on page 48

Comment: Are you still receiving the "Port not available" error?

Comment: yes , same error on matlab as well

Comment: Can you post a link to your USB to serial adaptor? Do you know if it is able to automatically toggle the RS485 bus (automatic direction control)?

Comment: it is justt a usb with 2 wires connected to RS485 ports of the device

Comment: Not all RS485 devices are capable of automatic direction control, and that is required for Modbus. Are you sure yours is even RS485?

Comment: Based on the documentation it is RS-485 but i do not understand what you mean by automatic direction control ?

Comment: Modbus works over a two-wire RS485 bus, that means the communication is half-duplex: the master sends a request and the slave sends its response. On a half-duplex bus there can be only one device talking (but there can be many devices listening). To avoid collisions each transceiver has two signals to indicate when they want to take control of the bus to talk (TXEN or transmit enable) and when they want to listen to what it's being transmitted (~RXEN). Most good quality USB-to-RS485 adaptors have these signals automatically handled in their hardware but some cheap devices need manual toggling

Comment: If you are not sure whether your device has the capability to automatically control the bus direction you can post a link to your device. You can find more details about Modbus and RS485 half-duplex in [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922031/modbus-error-invalid-message-incomplete-message-received-expected-at-least-2/56923891#56923891)

Comment: The link to my device is in the description " ATR-401" , click on it and it will direct you to the device datasheet